# horizontal offset for title rule

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Is there there a way to indent the title rule in the same way I've indented the heading text for the section?

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{4.5em}{}[\titlerule]
```

Sorry if this simple question, I just started using latex.
Thanks!

edit: I've tried:

```
[hspace{4.5em}\hrulefill]
```

but this seems to affect the vertical spacing

edit 2: minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{4.5em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Heading 1}
information about heading 1
\section{heading 2}
information about heading 2

\end{document}}
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe `[\hspace*{4.5em}\hrulefill]`

Comment: this also affects the vertical placement of my text. thanks though!

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to obtain it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{titlesec, lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}{%
  \Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{4.5em}{}%
    [\vspace*{-0.667\baselineskip}\hspace*{4.5em}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]